# server process that beats every second in Django

Tags: django, cron, celery, django-celery

In my project, several users access the same page, and when the group is there, then a certain process on the server side needs to run and change a model field in the database every second.

When they leave the page, the process must stop.

I know that it's doable using `Celery` `crontab` function, but I wonder if there are more efficient or compact way of achieving the same result in Django?

Comment: I think you need to deal with websockets instead of celery.